# How to meet user with loader and in background load all another data in svelte?

Tags: html, typescript, sveltekit, svelte-transition

I have a large animated content in Three.js written on Svelte, and I need to display a loader that wraps whole view until all packages and animations are loaded. But i need to make loader load first, and then only start loading rest components

I have some thought how to realize it in this sample

```xml
<script>
...
let startLoad = false
let loaded = false
onMount(() => startLoad = true)) // or add SetTimout to 1 millisecond that makes start true


</script> 
{#if !loaded} 
<p> loading <p> // this content wraps whole site with custom loader
{/if}
{#if startLoad}
<SomeComponentWithHugeAnimation onLoaded="()=> loaded=true"> 
{/if}
```

if you have better ideas, list them please

Ideas to how to realize this, wrapper loading to not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as above, but also added suspend from `threlte` to track `isLoaded`from store
on gltf file load.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).